# Loop over fieldnames in a MatLab structure

Tags: matlab, loops, struct

I have a MatLab "struct", with different "level" and "sub-structures". When printed to a cell, the data contained in the "struct", look like that:

```
report.COUNTRY.SOURCE.SCENARIO.CATEGORY.ENTITY = YEAR YEAR ...;
```

As a minimal example:

```
report.HUN.CRF2014.BASEYEAR.CAT0.CO2 = 1991 1992 1993 1994
report.HUN.CRF2014.BASEYEAR.CAT0.CH4 = 1995 1996 1997
report.HUN.CRF2014.BASEYEAR.CAT0.H2S = 1990 1991 1992
report.HUN.CRF2014.BASEYEAR.CAT1.N2 = 1991 1992 1993
report.HUN.CRF2014.BASEYEAR.CAT1.FGASES = 1990 1991 1992
```

In order to produce tables listing the different variables combinations, I would like to loop over the fieldnames contained within the "struct".

I am currently trying to write a function able to do that:

```
fields=fieldnames(struct);
for categoryidx=1:length(fields)
categoryname=fields{categoryidx};
    if isstruct(struct.(categoryname))
        category=fieldnames(struct.(categoryname));
        for entityidx = 1:length(category);
            entityname = category{entityidx};
            if isstruct(struct.(categoryname).(entityname))
            gases=fieldnames(struct.(categoryname).(entityname));
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Unfortunately, this is just producing anything! Does anyone has any idea how to loop over fieldnames in such a matlab structure? Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example of such a structure? Just make one up, so people can actually run the above code to try and help you...

Comment: First issue could be that your struct is called "struct" - probably this is already the reason. If not please simplify your example and post runnable code.

Comment: @thewaywewalk - This script is within a function. Therefore "struct" name change when calling the function for a specified "struct" (in my case "report"). I need to post an example of my "struct" in order to make this script runnable.

Comment: @steve it doesn't matter if its within a function or not. You use it as an local function variable and you overwrite the in-built function within that function. And if not `fields=fieldnames(struct);` will **always** return an empty result.

Comment: @thewaywewalk - I am not sure that I really understand your statement (sorry but I am a novice with MatLab). But, in my case when calling the function with the right name of the struct I do have a result. I am trying to post a minimal example of my structure.

Comment: The issue is that `struct` is a built-in command, so naming a variable 'struct' is likely causing havoc. Rename it to something like `myStruct` and see if you still get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out:
[struct2tabler](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/56165-struct2tabler--s--). This is a MATLAB function that recursively goes through a structure to convert into a table.

For example:

a.a = 5 
a.b.c = 10 
a.b.d = 15

Would return a table: 
a_a   a_b_c   a_b_d 
---------------------------
5         10           15

Disclaimer: I have written struct2tabler, so might be a little biased, however it was created out of a requirement, I think, very similar to yours.